# What is the precise method to render credentials in UI after restore?

Tags: android, react-native, hyperledger, wallet, aries

I have been exploring **aries-mobile-agent-react-native** wallet for a while. I am trying to add a backup and restore option in the Wallet.

Has anyone worked on this wallet?⏬

https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-mobile-agent-react-native

I am trying to restore credentials into wallet from backed up. **What is the exact way** to insert into credential array after **restore credentials** from anywhere (like database) and then render it (with existing one) in the mobile UI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you change your question title to what you really ask?

Comment: it is still not clear - answer to your question title is - yes, if somebody worked with it, but your real question is about credentials